# Semantic markup with Bootstrap Grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, semantic-markup

There are few way organize the Bootstrap Grid, e.g.

```
<div id='footer'>
   <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-6 footer-left'>
```

or

```
   <div id='footer' class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-6 footer-left'>
```

or

```
<div id='footer'>
   <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-6'>
          <div id='footer-left'>
```

Which one is more easy to maintain, assume you will add CSS positions (margin, padding etc) to the `footer` and `footer-left`

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1):

I know that some Bootstrap classes, such as container, row and the col-* have some predefined padding/margin already applied to them which helps lay the various elements out and collapse them down in the responsive view and so on.

Since the CSS of the ID takes priority over the CSS of the class, if I remember correctly, then doing something like your second option could result in some odd behavior. In general, I would go for the third option but it ultimately comes down to preference and if you feel you can work around any quirks that the other options might introduce.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='footer'>
   <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-6'>
          <div id='footer-left'>
```

Above code is best hierarchy to required output. If we follow `container -> row -> col-md-* -> user-defines-class` then it will make the `div` fully responsive and pure bootstrap related code. this hierarchy maintain perfect output of all `divs` regarding `margin, padding and center auto`

Answer (score 0):

how does look your layout? bootstrap has a few solution for you and you can choose what you need! in HTML5 better solution to use `<footer>` tag instead `<div class="footer">`, 'class="container"' has fixed width with paddings, 'class="container-fluid"' has only paddings, `class="row"` has negative margins which overlapping positive `container` paddings etc...